# Error talking to API Manager: {"name":"UniqueConstraintError","message":"Deployment already exists for the API"}

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

I am creating CICD pipeline for deploying mule proxy application to cloud hub. My approach is to using anypoint cli to automate the deployment. Using anypoint cli i am able to add api from exchange to api manager, but while deploying the proxy application to cloud hub i am getting the following error

Error: Error talking to API Manager: {"name":"UniqueConstraintError","message":"Deployment already exists for the API"} [code 400]

Below is the command which i am using to deploy the proxy application to cloudhub

api-mgr api deploy --applicationName muleweatherapi --gatewayVersion 4.4.0 --overwrite true 17946730

where 17946730 is the asset id.

Comment: It seems like you have deployed it once, and instead of overriding the previously deployed app, you might be trying to do a clean deploy with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

That API ID name may already be in use by another application deployed in CloudHub. Ensure that only one application has the API ID.

See this KB article for more details: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Unable-to-deploy-to-CloudHub-UniqueConstraintError

Comment: Hi Aled, I checked that article already, and that's why I have deleted all the api's from cloud hub but still getting this error.